# How can I use javascript to insert images randomly into a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript and I'm creating a game where a user re-arranges a table of pictures by clicking. The images are really scrambled pieces of a larger image that the user has to sort out.

The user clicks on one of the images in the table, then clicks another image in the table, and they swap positions. I have to use javascript for this, so Ive created a 3x4 table and filled it with 12 "partial" images that need to be re-arranged.

Each time the page loads, I need to have the images in each cell to be randomly assigned so that each game, the user has to sort the images in a different way.

To do this, I use a diffImage() function that picks a random image from an array of images that I have. So if one of my images is named "mario01.jpg", the function takes the image and makes it `<img src="mario01.png" />`.

My diffImage() function also takes that image that it selected out of the array so that the image won't be inserted for a second time into the table.

What I am wondering is, how do I incorporate the diffImage() function into my html where I set up the table so that every time the page loads, the images are in different cells?

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hw3CSS.css" type="text/css"/>
<title>Picture Scramble Game</title>
</head>
<script>
var imagelist = ["mario01.jpg", "mario02.jpg", "mario03.jpg", "mario04.jpg", "mario05.jpg", "mario06.jpg", "mario07.jpg", "mario08.jpg", "mario09.jpg", "mario10.jpg", "mario11.jpg", "mario12.jpg"];


function diffImage() {
    whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagelist.length);
    document.write('<img src="'+imagelist[whichImage]+'" />');
    imagelist.splice(whichImage,1);
}


</script>
<body onload="addEventListeners();">
</script>
<div id="table">
<table>
    <tr><td><img class="element" id="image1" src="mario02.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image2" src="mario02.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image3" src="mario01.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><img class="element" id="image4" src="mario05.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image5" src="mario04.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image6" src="mario06.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><img class="element" id="image7" src="mario09.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image8" src="mario08.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image9" src="mario07.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><img class="element" id="image10" src="mario11.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image11" src="mario10.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="element" id="image12" src="mario12.jpg" /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems like a fun problem that I might spend the time to work through for some SO rep if I didn't know I'd be doing someone else's homework for him.

Comment: Heh true, it does say homework at the top. I tried to leave some of the work to him... hopefully he'll learn something and build his own solution from it.

Comment: This is a homework assignment, but I'm not asking anyone to do it for me. I'm asking for ideas of how to do one small part of it, and I appreciate any helpful and constructive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the diffImage function so that it returns a value that is equal to the src of the image you want

Something like:

```
function diffImage() {
    var output = '';
    whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagelist.length);
    output = imagelist[whichImage];
    imagelist.splice(whichImage,1);
    return output;
}
```

Then go through all the images with something like:

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = diffImage();
document.getElementById("image2").src = diffImage();
etc...
```

I hope my answer helps you without giving away your homework assignment too much.

(PS: you will get more responses if it doesn't say homework in your code.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it...

Change your html to something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell1"></td>
        <td id="cell2"></td>
        <td id="cell3"></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td id="cell10"></td>
        <td id="cell11"></td>
        <td id="cell12"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then add something like this:

```
var cellElement, imageElement;
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    cellElement = document.getElementById("cell" + i);
    imageElement = document.createElement("img");
    imageElement.src = ""; // random image url spliced into here
    cellElement.appendChild(imageElement);
}
```

Alternatively, it may be easier (and certainly more flexible) to create the table and the cells inside it using Javascript as well.